# how to count the number of documents under nested fields in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch, just started to try out utilize the elasticsearch to do fulltext search on nodejs. Currently I have a problem to find out the count the number of item of the nested field. For example suppose this is my data:

```
{
  user1: {
    movies: [
      {
        title: 'eat'
      },
      {
        title: 'drink'
      }
    ],
    books: [
      {
        author: 'apple'
      }
    ]
  },
  user2: {
    movies: [
      {
        title: 'jump'
      },
      {
        title: 'punch'
      },
      {
        title: 'sleep'
      },
      {
        title: 'eat'
      }
    ],
    books: [
      {
        author: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

how to do a simple count of how many movies does user1 or user2 have?(2 and 4 in this case).

If it turns out to be surprisingly difficult, I could still fallback to store that number somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
let users = {
        user1: {
                movies: [
                        {
                                title: 'eat'
                        },
                        {
                                title: 'drink'
                        }
                ],
                books: [
                        {
                                author: 'apple'
                        }
                ]
        },
        user2: {
                movies: [
                        {
                                title: 'jump'
                        },
                        {
                                title: 'punch'
                        },
                        {
                                title: 'sleep'
                        },
                        {
                                title: 'eat'
                        }
                ],
                books: [
                        {
                                author: 'orange'
                        }
                ]
        }
}

console.log(`User1 count: ${users.user1.movies.length}`);
console.log(`User2 count: ${users.user2.movies.length}`);
```